# Adding svn commits to git repo

Tags: git, svn, bitbucket

We downloaded and converted an SVN repository to a git repository without the svn commit history and added some git commits.

Do you know how we can add those previous SVN commit history to the git repository without losing the new ones?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can, and testing with a simplified example repository this worked for me:

1. Install `git-svn` if you haven't already.
2. Clone the SVN repository with this command:

   ```
   git svn clone SVNURL /path/to/svnclone
   ```

   This creates a Git repository at `/path/to/svnclone` with the full Subversion commit history.
3. In the Git repository where you started to make changes, add `svnclone` as a remote, and rebase on top of it:

   ```
   cd /path/to/gitrepo
   git remote add svnclone /path/to/svnclone
   git fetch svnclone
   git rebase svnclone/master
   ```

This last step will take the commits in `svnclone` and replay your new commits on top of them. As a result, you will end up with exactly the same content in your project, but having the complete commit history, with both the old commits in Subversion, and the new commits you did in Git.